# Implementing Coordinate Descent with mini-batches

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement the Learned Coordinate Descent Algorithm (LCoD) from [this paper](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~kgregor/gregor-icml-10.pdf) by Karol Gregor and Yann Lecun with TensorFlow. The algorithm shows how to perform the forward pass (and backward propagation) with mini-batch size=1. I would like to extend this to larger mini-batch sizes.

In each step, (greedy) coordinate descent chooses the index of the largest component of `|Z - h(Z)|`, where `Z` is the sparse code (`N x C`), and `h()` is the proximal operator, such as the soft-thresholding function. `C` is the number of components/atoms in the dictionary. In the paper, `N = 1`, but I want to generalize this to `N >= 1`.

In the update step of algorithm 5:

```
for all j in [1, C]: B_j = B_j + S_jk e(t)
```

`k` is the index of the largest component from above. This step is not easy to  perform since index `k` is different for every example in the mini-batch (again, not a problem with `N = 1`, but problematic with `N > 1`).

A quick-fix would be to split the mini-batch into `N` rows, feed each row independently into the LCoD algorithm, then concatenate all `N` rows back into a full-sized matrix. However, I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution. On both CPU/GPU, I find the forward/back-propagation of this quick-fix to be very, very slow.

Comment: Did you finally implemented it?